# Regex Pattern for a Java Log

Tags: regex, logging, fluentd

I am trying to use the regex Parser Plugin in fluentd to index the logs of my application.

Here's a snippet of it.

`2020-05-06T22:34:50.860-0700 - WARN  [main] o.s.b.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor: Invalid JavaBean property 'pipeline' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void com.theoaal.module.pipeline.mbean.DynamicPhaseExecutionConfigurationMBeanBuilder.setPipeline(com.theplatform.module.pipeline.DynamicPipeline)]: [public void com.theplatform.module.pipeline.mbean.PhaseExecutionConfigurationMBeanBuilder.setPipeline(com.theoaal.module.pipeline.Pipeline)]`

I have used the regex101.com to match the regex pattern and I am not able to get a match.

`^(?<date>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})(?<timestamp>[A-Z][a-z]{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}\-\d{4})\s\-\s(?<loglevel>\[\w\]{6})\s+(?<class>\[[A-Z][a-z]+\])\s(?<message>.*)$`

Kindly help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[A-Z](?<timestamp>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}-\d{4})\s+-\s+(?<loglevel>\w+)\s+(?<class>\[\w+\])\s+(?<message>.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tomhQ/1)

Note, in your pattern, `\[\w\]{6}` only matches `[`, a single word char and six `]` chars. In the timestamp pattern, `[A-Z][a-z]{1}` requires two letters, but tere is a single `T`. Your "class" pattern requires a capitalized word with `[A-Z][a-z]+`, but `main` is all lowercase. You escape `-` outside of character classes unnecessarily, and you failed to escape a literal dot in the pattern.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - date: 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-`, 2 digits
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?<timestamp>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}-\d{4})` - 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `.`, 3 digits, `-` and 4 digits
- `\s+-\s+` - `-` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<loglevel>\w+)` - 1+ word chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<class>\[\w+\])` - `[`, 1+ word chars, `]`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<message>.*)` - the res of the line.

Copy and paste to `fluent.conf` or `td-agent.conf`:

```
<source>
  type tail
  path /var/log/foo/bar.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/foo-bar.log.pos
  tag foo.bar
  format /^(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[A-Z](?<timestamp>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}-\d{4})\s+-\s+(?<loglevel>\w+)\s+(?<class>\[\w+\])\s+(?<message>.*)/
</source>
```

[Test](https://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%5E%28%3F%3Cdate%3E%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%28%3F%3Ctimestamp%3E%5BA-Z%5D%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%5Cs%2B-%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Cloglevel%3E%5Cw%2B%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Cclass%3E%5C%5B%5Cw%2B%5C%5D%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Cmessage%3E.*%29&input=2020-05-06T22%3A34%3A50.860-0700%20-%20WARN%20%20%5Bmain%5D%20o.s.b.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor%3A%20Invalid%20JavaBean%20property%20%27pipeline%27%20being%20accessed%21%20Ambiguous%20write%20methods%20found%20next%20to%20actually%20used%20%5Bpublic%20void%20com.theoaal.module.pipeline.mbean.DynamicPhaseExecutionConfigurationMBeanBuilder.setPipeline%28com.theplatform.module.pipeline.DynamicPipeline%29%5D%3A%20%5Bpublic%20void%20com.theplatform.module.pipeline.mbean.PhaseExecutionConfigurationMBeanBuilder.setPipeline%28com.theoaal.module.pipeline.Pipeline%29%5D&time_format=):

[image]

Comment: I have added the same in the parsers.conf file but I am not getting the expected output. The entire line is taken as an event while I was trying to get it on the Splunk dashboard